# How to remove text cursor on Select in React Select library?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-select

I couldn't find a way to remove the blinking text cursor shown in the image. It shows up when Select is focused.

[image: Cursor in the middle of 'Size' word]

Here is my select code:

```
  <Select 
    options={sizeOptions}
    onChange={handleSelect}
    placeholder='Size'
    className='Select-container'
    classNamePrefix='Select'
    value={null}
  />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cursor shows up because the `Select` component uses an input.

If you add a [classNamePrefix](https://react-select.com/props#select-props) prop to the `Select` component you are able to target the input `div` using `css` and change the color to `transparent`, which the input inside the div inherits as its color:

```
<Select
  placeholder="Size"
  options={sizeOptions}
  className="Select-container"
  classNamePrefix="select"
/>
```

Changing the input color to transparent using the `.prefix__input` selector:

```
.select__input {
  color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For react-select v5, you can use the `styles` prop and the `input` key like this:

```
<Select
  styles={{
    input: (baseStyles) => ({
    ...baseStyles,
    color: 'transparent'
    })
  }}
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

Locate the class which has input tag inside and change the CSS

```
.Select-input > input {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #2196f3;
 }

.Select-input > input:focus {
 outline: none;
}
```